# Resizing UITextView in custom UITableViewCell according to contentSize

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextview

I am trying to make message bubble by myself. I am using a custom `UITableViewCell` class and trying to resize `UITextView` in it.

But the `UITextView` is resizing its height well but not width.

This is what I tried.

I created an xib;

[image]

As you can see there is 6 constraints in xib. Trailing, leading, top and bottom space constraints and max/min width constraints.

And here is the custom `UITableViewCell`'s `awakeFromNib(:)` method;

```
 override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.messageContent.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        self.messageContent.clipsToBounds = true
        self.messageContent.editable = false
        self.messageContent.scrollEnabled = false
        self.messageContent.sizeToFit()
        self.messageContent.layoutIfNeeded()
        let size = self.messageContent.sizeThatFits(CGSizeMake(messageContent.contentSize.width, CGFloat.max))
        messageContent.bounds.size = size  
        // Initialization code
    }
```

When I run this code, here is the result;

[image]
This is working a little bit but not all the way. I want to make width constant and height flexible after 1 line but before that; I mean if there is a 1 line, text I want to make width flexible and height constant.

I would be glad if someone help. 
Happy coding!

**EDIT:**

When I try to delete trailing constraint or decrease it, layout goes like this;

[image]

Comment: Try remove trailing space. Or decrease its priority.

Comment: I tried, when i do that, textview height goes weird. all heights be equal to max height. Please check question, I edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added leading, bottom and top constraints and setted width constraint less then or equal to 250 and problem solved!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by changing your xib to use just a UITextView with no constraints.

[image]

Then make the message class look like this, which sets a max width of 300 but will shrink if there is less text and the height will grow as needed.

```
import UIKit

class MessageTextView: UITextView {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        layer.cornerRadius = 5
        clipsToBounds = true
        editable = false
        scrollEnabled = false
        sizeToFit()
        layoutIfNeeded()
        let size = sizeThatFits(CGSizeMake(contentSize.width > 300 ? 300 : contentSize.width, CGFloat.max))
        bounds.size = size
    }
}
```

Comment: After I asked this question, I thought if I can limit the UITextView's width, it could work. And your question is some kind of that in my opinion. But your suggestion didn't work. I tried something like that but UITextView's width goes equal in every cell. I printed `contentSize.width` before and after `bounds.size = size` line; and here is the output for every text view;
`OLD TEXTVIEW WIDTH:::359.0

TEXTVIEW WIDTH:::375.0`

Comment: Do you need to use UITableViewCell?

Comment: yes i have xcode 7.2. actually I solved it by using constraints, I wrote an answer. Thank you anyway:)